# changing diffirent layout file without restating activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, landscape-portrait

I have two seperate xml file for potrait and landscape view of an activity, but when I rotate my phone xml file changes but activity restarts. How can I change layout file without restarting activity.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach to this would be to use a **ViewModel** with your activity so that even if it gets destroyed, your data will persist in the ViewModel and can be reloaded once the view is created in the landscape orientation.

However, if you still wish to handle the layout change without restarting the activity, you will need to do the following changes

1. Set the `android:configChanges` flag in your **AndroidManifest** to `orientation`

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation"/>
   ```
2. Override the `onConfigurationChanged` method in your activity and load the new view. This part is a little tricky as you will have to discard the previous view before you inflate the new one. One approach would be to have a container in your activity and you can load two fragments in it, one for portrait and one for landscape orientation.

For more information, you can read this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange)

*Keep in mind that while this will work, using the android:configChanges attribute is not recommended*